# How to get 'IS NULL' where clause values if initial condition returns none in oracle

Tags: oracle, null, where-clause

I have a table with values as follows

[![ID   S_ID    NAME
1           James
2   2455    Patrick
3   2566    Sam
4   25988   Rick][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCBgL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCBgL.png)

My requirement is to get the NAME based on S_ID and if the given S_ID is not in the table then get the NAME with no S_ID

EX:
`SELECT NAME FROM STUDENTS WHERE S_ID=2455`

The result would be **Patrick**

`SELECT NAME FROM STUDENTS WHERE S_ID=2411`

The result should be **James**

I have tried

`select NAME from STUDENTS where S_ID=2455 or S_ID IS NULL`

It gives be bot **James** and **Patrick**

I would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL> with students (id, s_id, name) as
  2    (select 2, 2389, 'Patrick' from dual union all
  3     select 1, null, 'James'   from dual union all
  4     select 3, 2566, 'Sam'     from dual
  5    )
  6  select name from students where s_id = &&par_s_id
  7    and exists (select null from students where s_id = &&par_s_id)
  8  union all
  9  select name from students where s_id is null
 10    and not exists (select null from students where s_id = &&par_s_id);
Enter value for par_s_id: 2389

NAME
-------
Patrick                               --> because S_ID = 2389 exists in a table

SQL> undefine par_s_id
SQL> /
Enter value for par_s_id: 123456

NAME
-------
James                                 --> because S_ID = 123456 doesn't exist

SQL>
```

As you already have the table, you'd use code from line #6 onward.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe,

As per my understanding if S_ID is found in the STUDENT table it should return the NAME of the student, if S_ID is not found the query should return a message as 'No #S_ID'.

Please let me know if I am making any mistake in understanding your question !

[Solution]
Its a Tsql so we can use it as is in the sql or in any language. And note I have tested it in MSSQL but the approach remains the same.

`declare @sidInput int
set @sidInput = 2455
if exists (select NAME from STUDENTS where S_ID = @sidInput) 
begin
    select NAME from STUDENTS where S_ID = @sidInput
end
else
begin
    declare @outputMsg varchar(20)
    set @outputMsg = 'No ' + convert( varchar(10), @sidInput) 
    select top 1 @outputMsg as NAME from STUDENTS where S_ID not in ( @sidInput ) 
end`

[Test Cases]

1) For Input @sidInput = 2455

```
Output - NAME as Patrick
```

2) For Input @sidInput = 2411

```
Output - NAME as James
```

3) For Input @sidInput = 2222 #S_ID value not found in STUDENT table

```
Output - NAME as No 2222
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Regards,

Arnab

Comment: When s_id was not found, I need the name of the student who doesn't have the s-id. Even if there are more than 1 result, I need all of them.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe,

try this t-sql (and pardon me I was using maria db - so used it ) . basically it remains the same as for my above response its just that I have updated the else block. ( Note - If you are using MySQL can simply use this as it for testing )

`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS prod_studentName;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE``prod_studentName`()`

`BEGIN`

```
declare sidValue int;
set sidValue = 2389;
if exists (select NAME from STUDENT where S_ID = sidValue ) 
then
    select NAME from STUDENT where S_ID = sidValue;
else
    select NAME from STUDENT where S_ID is NULL;
end if;`
```

`END$$`

`DELIMITER ;`

refer to the attached image for the table inputs - [image]

test outcomes

## positive test - lookup for `s_id = 2389`

outcome - [image]

## negative test - lookup for `s_id = 7777` this id doesn't even exist at all

outcome - [image]

hope this helps you